# Failing to remove single variable from collection in Salesforce Flow

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, collection

**What I'm trying to do**

Using Record Triggered Flow, when Opportunity is updated, I want it to retrieve all the Opportunities related under the same account like in screenshot below

[image: Get Opportunity List]

Then I will use Assignment to try to remove the the **first** record from the List either using the **Remove First** or **Remove Position 1** like below:

[image: Remove first function]

[image: Remove position function]

Thinking that it would remove the first record from the {!TempOpptyList} . But NO it doesn't remove the first record.

1. Why does **Remove First** need a value? I just want to remove it from the variable.
2. Why does **Remove Position 1** not work?
3. Why is Flow so unintuitive? Should I just do this in Apex code instead?

Answer (score 2):

You don't really get what `Remove First` means:

`Remove First` - The first instance of `Value` is removed from the collection in `Variable`. This is why the `Value` is required, it does not remove the first element from `Variable`, but rather finds first occurrence of `Value` in `Variable` and removes it.

About the second question, you are right, this should work as you expect, so I am also confused about it:

`Remove Position` - `Value` specifies a position in the collection. The item at the position is removed from the collection in `Variable`.

[Docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_operators_assignment.htm&type=5).

Comment: Any chance remove position is zero indexed, and you need 0 there not 1?

Comment: It's totally not, because in documentation clearly stated that `Make sure that Value at run time is a positive integer that is within the range of the number of items in the collection in Variable.` @MattLacey

Comment: For some reason my Flow debug kept failing. But anyway after coming back to the problem, with a fresh set of records, I realised it worked perfectly using the Remove Position. 
I find it strange that Remove First works that way. In conventional programming, its just pop the first record period.

Comment: Seems like bad naming to me, `RemoveFirstInstanceOf` would have made more sense!

Answer (score 1):

The [Collection Actions installable extension](https://unofficialsf.com/list-actions-for-flow/) adds an action called Get First that may be what you're looking for.